# Web root Alias directory

Tags: apache2, directory

I want to use another directory come to use in my web server with Apache in Ubuntu?

I'm new user in Ubuntu. I want step by step for understand.
Help me please.

ps.
KUbuntu 14.10,
apache2

Answer (score 4):

Quoted from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html

> Files Outside the DocumentRoot
>
> There are frequently circumstances where it is necessary to allow web
> access to parts of the filesystem that are not strictly underneath the
> DocumentRoot. Apache offers several different ways to accomplish this.
> On Unix systems, symbolic links can bring other parts of the
> filesystem under the DocumentRoot. For security reasons, Apache will
> follow symbolic links only if the Options setting for the relevant
> directory includes FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch.
>
> Alternatively, the Alias directive will map any part of the filesystem
> into the web space. For example, with
>
> Alias /docs /var/web the URL http://www.example.com/docs/dir/file.html
> will be served from /var/web/dir/file.html.....

#### What does this mean?

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

It will open:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Now add the alias and the directory permissions , suppose add /pics and I will use the Pictures directory in my home to server it.

output would be like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    Alias /docs /home/user/Pictures
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/user/Pictures>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Now restart apache service

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now when typing `localhost/pics` this will serve from `/home/user/Pictures` instead of `/var/www`

[image]

Comment: i have only '000-default.conf' in /etc/apache2/sites-available.

Comment: in side this file no have <Directory> tage